# How to create a responsive 4 div diamond?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project where I have a div diamond of pictures that needs to be responsive.

The picture below shows the diamond in div I have created, but it doesn't work in all sizes. I want the diamond to react responsively to the browser size, so it always fits.

[image: current website with nonresponsive diamond]

I have [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CfNb/), but it is not responsive. Just to show what I want, and I have been trying to create.

```html
<div id="page">
<div id="main">
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box green"></div>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box yellow"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
#page {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:500px;
    min-width:500px;
}
#main {
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    height:35%;
    width:35%;
    margin-right:5%;
    margin-top:5%;
}
.blue {
    background-color:blue;
}
.green {
    background-color:green;
}
.red {
    background-color:red;
}
.yellow {
    background-color:#ffd54f;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated :-)

Comment: Could we have a screen of what is supposed to be drawn? Your example has empty text and doesn't print anything by me so I'm unsure what you mean by "diamond"

Comment: I have added in a screenshot of what I have till now.

Comment: Hmm okay, I think you might consider testing all that on firefox, or maybe it's just a problem with me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start with a responsive base:

```
#main {
    width: 35%;
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 35%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The trick is to set the vertical dimension as padding percentage, that is calculated on the width of the parent. (So it is always a square)

Now set the diamonds, translated as percentages.

```
.box {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.blue {
    background-color:blue;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-75%, 100%) rotate(45deg);
}
.green {
    background-color:green;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 25%) rotate(45deg);
}
.red {
    background-color:red;
    -webkit-transform: translate(75%, 100%) rotate(45deg);
}
.yellow {
    background-color:#ffd54f;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 175%) rotate(45deg);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CfNb/11/show)

Comment: Nice! I can work this around to work perfect with my project! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: OK it can be done with CSS alone. Updated fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/5CfNb/5/

Not sure if this can be done with CSS alone, but here's my solution using a few lines of jQuery. Depending on the aspect ratio though, it won't be a perfect 'diamond', so still needs some tweaking. But I hope this helps.

```
$('#main').height($(window).height());
$('#main').width($(window).width());

$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#main').height($(window).height());
    $('#main').width($(window).width());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5CfNb/4/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. The pictures needs to keep their square form. Not getting askew when re-sizing the browser.

Comment: Münter, does it need to be fluid? Giving your #main a fixed width/height will solve this but ofcourse destroy the fluid responsivity. If it doesn't need to be fluid I suggest using mediaqueries to set the fixed width/height of the #main div.

Comment: Would be awesome with fluid solution, but yeah I guess mediaqueries could solve it

Answer (score 0):

This could also help you a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/bJLYn/1/

```
#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -15% 0 0 -15%;
    height: 0px;
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 30%;
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.box {
    display: block;
    width: 45%;
    height: 45%;
    position: absolute;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.green {
    background: green;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.red {
    background: red;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.yellow {
    background: #ffd54f;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```